# How to let PowerShell display a multiline exception

Tags: powershell

When I throw a multiline exception message, PowerShell seems to always replace the newline characters with spaces.

E.g.

```
Line 1: $newline = [System.Environment]::NewLine
Line 2: throw "multiline$newline test"
```

Yields:

```
Exception: Test.ps1:2:1        
Line |
  19 |  throw "multiline$newline test"
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | multiline  test
```

For larger multiline exception texts ideally the newline characters should not get replaced.

Any clue how I can ask PowerShell to leave the newline characters?

```
$PSVersionTable   

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

```
$ErrorView
ConciseView
```

If I switch to 'DetailedView' then the newline is not replaced.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using and what's your current `$ErrorView` value? Error label/FQEI is rendered correctly (with the line break) in 7.2.6 for me in both Concise, Detailed and Normal error view

Comment: I'm able to reproduce for `$ErrorView = 'ConciseView'` in PS 7.2.6. That's propably just how it works for `ConciseView`.